# C# Windows Form application IAsyncOperation

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm create a Windows Form Application and I'm trying to use `IAsyncOperation` to use on a Bluetooth connection, but I'm always receive the same error:

The type `IAsyncOperation<>` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly.

What reference is needed?

The code I'm using is:

```
BluetoothLEDevice device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(address);
```

Comment: It tells you in the error message, you must add Windows.Foundation

Answer (score 0):

This one:
using System.Threading.Tasks;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks(v=vs.110).aspx